# C Webvserver – STDIN, sockets and CGI piping

Tags: c, sockets, webserver, pipe, dup2

I want to create a remote control for [GNUNet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNUnet), so I started writing a self-made multithreaded-generical-purpose webserver for the GNU OS, able to authenticate users (reading from the [system user database](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Lookup-User.html)) and able to execute generic CGI programs/scripts. I started from scratch and it's just a draft for now. However, everything seems to work fine.

I have just a question.

As you know, a CGI programs/scripts read the POST string from the STDIN and send their content to the STDOUT. The following is (part of) the code I wrote. And it seems to work.

```c
if (pipe(cgiPipe))
{
  perror("pipe");
}

cgiPid = fork();

if (cgiPid == 0)
{

  /* child */

  /* piping the POST content... */

  /* first, send the truncated part of the POST string contained within the request string... */
  if (nPOSTLength && (nSentChrs = write(cgiPipe[1], sPOSTSegment, 
      nReqLen + requestString - sPOSTSegment)) > 0)
  {
    nPOSTLength -= nSentChrs;

    /* after, read and send the rest of the POST string not received yet... */
    while (nPOSTLength > 0 && (nReadChrs = read(nRemote, reservedBuffer, 
        BUFFER_SIZE_PER_USER)) > 0 && (nSentChrs = write(cgiPipe[1], reservedBuffer, 
        nReadChrs)) > 0 && nReadChrs == nSentChrs)
    {
      nPOSTLength -= nReadChrs;
    }

    if (nReadChrs < 0)
    {
      printf("Error reading POST string.\n");
      goto closeThread;
    }
    if (nSentChrs < 0)
    {
      printf("Error sending POST string.\n");
      goto closeThread;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    write(cgiPipe[1], "(null)", 6);
  }

  close(cgiPipe[1]);

  /* redirecting the output of the pipe to the STDIN of the child process */
  dup2(cgiPipe[0], STDIN_FILENO);
  /* redirecting STDOUT of the child process to the remote client */
  dup2(nRemote, STDOUT_FILENO);
  setuid(nUserID);

  if (execve(sLocalPath, NULL, aCGIEnv))
  {
    /* unable to execute CGI... */
    perror("execve");
    sendString(nRemote,
        "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
        "Content-length: 97\r\n"
        "Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n"
        "<!doctype html><html><head><title>CGI Error</title></head><body><h1>CGI Error.</h1></body></html>\r\n"
    );
  }

  goto closeThread;

}
else if (cgiPid > 0)
{

  /* parent */

  close(cgiPipe[0]);

  /* wait for child process. */
  if (waitpid(cgiPid, NULL, 0) == -1)
  {
    perror("wait");
  }

  goto closeThread;

}
else
{

  /* parent */

  perror("fork");

  /* let's try to send it as normal file, if the user has the right permissions... */

}
```

As you can see, **before** executing the CGI program, **the whole POST string** is received from the client and piped (first the truncated part of it contained within the request string – usually few bytes – and then the rest). **Then**, the CGI program is executed.

And now my question…

If I try to upload a file of several MBs, several MBs are piped **before** the invocation of the CGI: **is there any way to redirect the socket directly to the STDIN of the new process, in order to not read it before?** But, for sure, I have to send the read truncated part of the POST string, before. So, I can schematize what I would like to do in this way:

- piping a string (few bytes) to the STDIN, then
- redirecting the socket (the client) to the STDIN, then
- executing an external process (the CGI program)

Is it possible? Can you show me *how*?

Comment: Some declarations would help.

Comment: This `write(..., nReqLen + requestString - sPOSTSegment))` looks wrong. The 3rd parameter should be an integer. I'd expected this to make the compiler yell out a warning, at least.

Comment: @alk It's correct! requestString is an array of characters, sPOSTSegment is a pointer to a character of that array [got through: sPOSTSegment = 4 + strstr(requestString, "\r\n\r\n") – when found], so sPOSTSegment *minus* requestString is the offset of the POST segment starting to count from requestString. And, if I do TOTAL_LENGTH_OF_THE_REQUEST - POST_OFFSET, then I get the length of the POST segment. So ... nReqLen + requestString - sPOSTSegment ... is the length of the POST segment (truncated or not) contained within the request string. It's an integer! And GCC doesn't yell out any warning.

Comment: Why do you need to pipe a string to the stdin? can't you just write the string to stdin?

Comment: @GiuseppePes I want to send a little string to the STDIN and *then* to pipe **a socket** to the STDIN! Any idea?

Comment: @grufo basically you want to redirect the stdin to a socket

Comment: @GiuseppePes Yessss! Could you hack my code? :)

Comment: @grufo: I wasn't aware `requestString ` is a char array also ...

Answer (score 1):

Solved!!

I just had to put the sending process inside the parent rather than the child. In this way the CGI is executed immediately:

```c
if (pipe(cgiPipe))
{
  perror("pipe");
}

cgiPid = fork();

if (cgiPid == 0)
{

  /* child */

  /* piping the POST content... */

  close(cgiPipe[1]);

  /* redirecting the output of the pipe to the STDIN of the child process */
  dup2(cgiPipe[0], STDIN_FILENO);
  /* redirecting STDOUT of the child process to the remote client */
  dup2(nRemote, STDOUT_FILENO);
  setuid(nUserID);

  if (execve(sLocalPath, NULL, aCGIEnv))
  {
    /* unable to execute CGI... */
    perror("execve");
    sendString(nRemote,
        "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
        "Content-length: 97\r\n"
        "Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n"
        "<!doctype html><html><head><title>CGI Error</title></head><body><h1>CGI Error.</h1></body></html>\r\n"
    );
  }

  goto closeThread;

}
else if (cgiPid > 0)
{

  /* parent */

  close(cgiPipe[0]);

  /* first, send the truncated part of the POST string contained within the request string... */
  if (nPOSTLength && (nSentChrs = write(cgiPipe[1], sPOSTSegment, 
      nReqLen + requestString - sPOSTSegment)) > 0)
  {
    nPOSTLength -= nSentChrs;

    /* after, read and send the rest of the POST string not received yet... */
    while (nPOSTLength > 0 && (nReadChrs = read(nRemote, reservedBuffer, 
        BUFFER_SIZE_PER_USER)) > 0 && (nSentChrs = write(cgiPipe[1], reservedBuffer, 
        nReadChrs)) > 0 && nReadChrs == nSentChrs)
    {
      nPOSTLength -= nReadChrs;
    }

    if (nReadChrs < 0)
    {
      printf("Error reading POST string.\n");
      goto closeThread;
    }
    if (nSentChrs < 0)
    {
      printf("Error sending POST string.\n");
      goto closeThread;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    write(cgiPipe[1], "(null)", 6);
  }

  /* wait for child process. */
  if (waitpid(cgiPid, NULL, 0) == -1)
  {
    perror("wait");
  }

  goto closeThread;

}
else
{

  /* parent */

  perror("fork");

  /* let's try to send it as normal file, if the user has the right permissions... */

}
```

Thank you for your help!

And… let's hope to see a remote control for GNUNet as early as possble! :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by replacing the file descriptor `STDIN_FILENO` with the opened socket using [dup2()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html). You should also then close the original socket in the child process:

```
dup2(socket_fd, STDIN_FILENO);
close(socket_fd); ; 
execve("cgi_process", args, env);
```

The [execve](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) puts into execution another process whose `STDIN` is bound to `socket_fd`.

Comment: With this example the little string is lost. I need to concatenate a little string followed by what the socket sends, together, to the STDIN_FILENO of the CGI. So, in few words, when the CGI program do *read(STDIN_FILENO, ...)* it musts receive the little string and then start to receive from the socket (like what I made with a pipe). Is it possible without sending the whole content before? Or, have you any possible alternative to the “preload” I made?

Comment: Essentially I want the STDIN to be be composed of two parts: **[ MY_LITTLE_STRING ---- WHAT_THE_SOCKET_SENDS_BUT_NOT_YET_KNOWN ]** and the CGI should read from it, starting to “talk” with the socket only after have read the string contained within the STDIN. Instead, the STDIN I made with my actual code is the following: **[ MY_LITTLE_STRING ---- WHAT_THE_SOCKET_*SENT*_ALREADY_PRELOADED_AND_PIPED ]** Is that clear now? I want to avoid any kind of “preload”.